# Bars intended to be stacked are shifting and NOT Aligned

Tags: pgfplots, alignment, bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart, but when I plot the three sets of datapoints, they are not aligned/shifted incorrectly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Number 1985-2021,
bar width=3pt,
ybar=5pt,
%ybar=-1cm, % because of bar width=1cm
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
       % axis lines=left,
         enlarge y limits=0.01,
         enlarge x limits=0.1,
%enlarge x limits={abs=2},
xlabel={Year},
ybar stacked, ymin=0, ymax=380,
xlabel style={yshift=-4ex},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
xtick={1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020},
ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400},
xticklabel style={rotate=90},
xticklabel style = {yshift=0.5ex},
]

\addplot [fill=black] coordinates {(1985,0)(1986,0)(1987,0)(1988,0)(1989,0)(1990,40)(1991,47)(1992,57)(1993,59)(1994,58)(1995,88)(1996,77)(1997,67)(1998,69)(1999,92)(2000,78)(2001,75)(2002,86)(2003,85)(2004,58)(2005,60)(2006,50)(2007,76)(2008,64)(2009,80)(2010,76)(2011,58)(2012,50)(2013,56)(2014,37)(2015,49)(2016,49)(2017,55)(2018,69)(2019,91)(2020,80)(2021,84)};

\addplot [fill=red] coordinates {(1985,86)(1986,219) (1987,167)(1988,172)(1989,215)(1990,182)(1991,201)(1992,228)(1993,235)(1994,210)(1995,192)(1996,203)(1997,212)(1998,208)(1999,228)(2000,290)(2001,217)(2002,176)(2003,188)(2004,170)(2005,205)(2006,179)(2007,188)(2008,168)(2009,147)(2010,148)(2011,151)(2012,101)(2013,138)(2014,137)(2015,97)(2016,71)(2017,128)(2018,158)(2019,150)(2020,142)(2021,27)};

\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(1985,0)(1986,0)(1987,0)(1988,0)(1989,0)(1990,0)(1991,0)(1992,0)(1993,0)(1994,0)(1995,0)(1996,0)(1997,0)(1998,0)(1999,0)(2000,0)(2001,0)(2002,0)(2003,0)(2004,0)(2005,0)(2006,0)(2007,0)(2008,0)(2009,0)(2010,0)(2011,68)(2012,85)(2013,58)(2014,71)(2015,103)(2016,78)(2017,56)(2018,19)(2019,25)(2020,46)(2021,33)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of Misalignment]

Answer (score 1):

- If you in your MWE remove `ybar=5pt` diagram will give correct result. This you discover in your answer too.
- `ybar=<width>` has sense in non stacked bar diagrams, where it define distance between bars around given coordinates.
- Width of diagram is a bit too narrow that in it be sufficient space for all bars, consequently they overlap, however it should not be wider than `\textwidth` (as you set in your answer).

One possible solution for your diagram, where data for bars are collected in table  and a bit changed styles for ticks labels.

**Edit:**
Removed are not used library and package (`units`, `siunitx`) as well obsolete package  `filecontents` which is now part of LaTeX kernel.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % recent version

\begin{filecontents}{xdata.data}
x       y1      y2      y3
1985    86      0       0
1986    219     0       0
1987    167     0       0
1988    172     0       0
1989    215     0       0
1990    182     40      0 
1991    201     47      0
1992    228     57      0
1993    235     59      0
1994    210     58      0
1995    192     88      0
1996    203     77      0
1997    212     67      0
1998    208     69      0
1999    228     92      0
2000    290     78      0
2001    217     75      0
2002    176     86      0
2003    188     85      0
2004    170     58      0
2005    205     60      0
2006    179     50      0
2007    188     76      0
2008    168     64      0
2009    147     80      0
2010    148     76      0
2011    151     58      68
2012    101     50      85
2013    138     56      58
2014    137     37      71
2015    97      49      103
2016    71      49      78
2017    128     55      56
2018    158     69      19
2019    150     91      25
2020    142     80      46
2021    27      84      33 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,
   title={Numbers},
    ybar stacked,
    xmin=1983,  xmax=2023,  ymin=0, ymax=400,
    bar width=2mm,
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
%xtick={1985,1990,...,2020},
ytick={0,100,...,400},
minor tick num=4,
xlabel={Year},
xtick align=outside,
ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
legend pos=north east,
            ]
\addplot    table [y=y1] {xdata.data};
\addplot    table [y=y2] {xdata.data};
\addplot    table [y=y3] {xdata.data};

\legend{S1, S2, S3}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, after more investigation, I was able to stack them by changing the addplot approach; however, I am sitll not sure what is wrong with the first approach.

```
    \documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % or whatever version you have
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=1.3\textwidth,    % set width
height=0.8\textwidth, % and height
   title={Numbers},
    ybar stacked, ymin=0, xmin=1983,xmax=2023,ymax=400,
    bar width=2mm,
x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
xlabel style={yshift=-4ex},
nodes near coords align={vertical},
xtick={1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020},
ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380,400},
xlabel={Year},
xtick align=outside,
xticklabel style={rotate=75},
xticklabel style = {yshift=0.4ex},
  ]

    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1985,86)(1986,219) (1987,167)(1988,172)(1989,215)(1990,182)(1991,201)(1992,228)(1993,235)(1994,210)(1995,192)(1996,203)(1997,212)(1998,208)(1999,228)(2000,290)(2001,217)(2002,176)(2003,188)(2004,170)(2005,205)(2006,179)(2007,188)(2008,168)(2009,147)(2010,148)(2011,151)(2012,101)(2013,138)(2014,137)(2015,97)(2016,71)(2017,128)(2018,158)(2019,150)(2020,142)(2021,27)};

    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1985,0)(1986,0)(1987,0)(1988,0)(1989,0)(1990,40)(1991,47)(1992,57)(1993,59)(1994,58)(1995,88)(1996,77)(1997,67)(1998,69)(1999,92)(2000,78)(2001,75)(2002,86)(2003,85)(2004,58)(2005,60)(2006,50)(2007,76)(2008,64)(2009,80)(2010,76)(2011,58)(2012,50)(2013,56)(2014,37)(2015,49)(2016,49)(2017,55)(2018,69)(2019,91)(2020,80)(2021,84)};

    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1985,0)(1986,0)(1987,0)(1988,0)(1989,0)(1990,0)(1991,0)(1992,0)(1993,0)(1994,0)(1995,0)(1996,0)(1997,0)(1998,0)(1999,0)(2000,0)(2001,0)(2002,0)(2003,0)(2004,0)(2005,0)(2006,0)(2007,0)(2008,0)(2009,0)(2010,0)(2011,68)(2012,85)(2013,58)(2014,71)(2015,103)(2016,78)(2017,56)(2018,19)(2019,25)(2020,46)(2021,33)};

  \legend{\strut S1,\strut  S2,\strut  S3}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!